# Low speed when the output in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When click on run application to phone or emulator in Android Studio, i should wait 15 min or up !

I have't this problem before and running application in phone / emulator on 1 min! but now when running application in phone / emulator i should wait 15 min or up to build **`Gradle`** !!!

How can i fix this problem and faster to build **`Gradle`** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue.Try these steps to make faster builds upto 3x faster:

- Make sure you don't have unnecessary gradle dependencies
- In the settings go to compiler-check combine independent modules parallel
- In the settings go to gradle and then click on offline mode.(This will cause your gradle to not to use internet while building project,dont use this if you are adding any new dependency)

Thanks,hope it'll help.